# Does Closure support JSDoc array syntax like `string[]`?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am having trouble finding out whether Closure supports JSDoc array syntax such as `string[]`.

I don't see it documented on https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System#user-content-the-javascript-type-language . However, JSDoc supports it, and it has been around a while, so I'm surprised Closure wouldn't support it also.

(JSdoc implies it is not supported in Closure per https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html , and mentions this in its `catharsis` type parser: https://github.com/hegemonic/catharsis , but I didn't know if this could be outdated info.)

If it is supported, I'd also like to know whether the optional `=` can be added immediately after it (without surrounding the previous expression in parentheses).

(As a bonus, I'd like to know whether the Record Type can have optional keys in Closure as through `{key?: number}`.)

Comment: Related to https://github.com/jsdoctypeparser/jsdoctypeparser/issues/110#issuecomment-596094182 ;)

Comment: Looks like only `Array<>` is [documented](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System) so it's not supported. Note also [the readme in catharsis](https://github.com/hegemonic/catharsis/blame/master/README.md#L40) that says: `var jsdocType = 'string[]';  // Closure Compiler expects Array.<string>`

Answer (score 1):

JSDocs and Closure Compiler have their differences. Use the [Closure documentation](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/) for details.

The type of an array of strings in closure is `Array<string>`.

Comment: Sure, and though as mentioned, I looked at the docs, does anyone have any first-hand experience, if not evidence from open issues, or locations in source, that this lack of support referenced by JSDoc (which can be very much out of date in places) is current? Thanks!

Comment: "The Closure Compiler's type language derives from the annotations used by the JSDoc document-generation tool, although over the years it has diverged. This document describes the set of annotations and type expressions that the Closure Compiler understands." --https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler So  use the Closure documentation (and not the JSDocs documentation)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the Closure docs in my original post also. But sometimes docs are behind their own implementation.